# How can Swift CMPedometerData update every step instead of delaying and updating the step count every few seconds?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I've been trying to get the CMPedometerData to update itself for every step user takes once started.

I've tried with a timer that forces updates, but it still only updates every few steps- is there a way to grab the pedometer signal another way? This question was last brought up 5 years ago, I'd be grateful for anything people may have come up with since, or any suggestions.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it is possible because I think that internally Core Motion doesn't (and can't) update every step. It uses sophisticated motion analysis to determine how many steps are taken since the device may be in different orientations depending on how it is placed in your pocket or a bag or even if you are actually in a vehicle that is vibrating. Even Apples own fitness and health apps only update every few steps.

Comment: @Paulw11 Sounds logical. Can this information be found within any of Apple's official documentation? It could serve as evidence if needed in the future.